# Wrote javascript to dynamically create table. Need help validating user input

Tags: javascript, validation, dynamic, html-table

I already have a table being created in javascript. It is based off user input and will check to make sure the value entered is a number. But how do I ALSO make it check to make sure the values entered are 
higher then 0
and less then 10

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homework 1</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function doWork(){
    var rows = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var columns = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    //alert(rows);
    //alert(columns);
    if(isNaN(rows) == true || isNaN(columns) == true){
        document.getElementById('tablePlacement').innerHTML = "Input must be integer";
    }
    else{
    var htmlInput = "";
    htmlInput += "<table border='1'>";
    htmlInput += "<tr>";

    //Column Headers
    for (i = 0; i <= columns; i++){
        htmlInput += ("<td><b>" + i + "</b></td>");
    }
    htmlInput += "</tr>";
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
        htmlInput += ("</br><tr><td><b>" + i + "</b></td>");

        for (j = 1; j<= columns; j++){
            var multiplyResult = i * j;
            htmlInput += ("<td>" + multiplyResult + "</td>");
        }
        htmlInput += "</tr>";
    }
    htmlInput += "</table>";
    document.getElementById('tablePlacement').innerHTML = htmlInput;
    }

    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="input1Form">
        Rows: <input type="text" id="input1">
    </form>
    <form id="input2Form">
        Columns: <input type="text" id="input2">
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="doWork()">Enter</button>
    <div id="tablePlacement">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(rows <=0 || rows >= 10){
    document.getElementById('tablePlacement').innerHTML = "Input rows must be between 1 and 9";
}

 if(cols <=0 || cols >= 10){
    document.getElementById('tablePlacement').innerHTML = "Input cols must be between 1 and 9";
}
```

Comment: I know how to write the code. I'm more confused about where to actually place it. Would this be a nested if statement. How would it work?

Comment: You could just put all conditions into one if statement like this `if (rows is not a number, or rows <= 0, or rows >= 10, or cols is not a number, or cols is <= 0, or cols is >= 10) { render generic error message like "Rows and Columns must be positive numbers less than 10" } else { ... render table ... }`